# Millisecond interval for DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone

I'm using a DispatcherTimer to call a void in C#:

```
        counter = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        counter.Tick += new EventHandler(counter_Tick);
        counter.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        counter.Start();
```

However I would like the interval to be a few milliseconds, TimeSpan's parameters are hours,minutes,seconds and only accepts integers (as far as I can see). Is there a work around for DispatcherTimer? I've tried Timer but I cannot use it (missing reference apparently)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TimeSpan` has a constructor that takes milliseconds: [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c7z43tw(v=vs.110).aspx). Basically, use `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, milliseconds);`

Comment: @EBrown definitely post this as an aswer I think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `TimeSpan` object has a constructor that takes milliseconds as a parameter:

MSDN has the details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c7z43tw(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically, replace `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)` with `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, millisecondTimeout)`.

Answer (score 9):

Another way

```
  counter.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although @EBrown's answer already tells you how to use milliseconds with a `DispatcherTimer`, its precision is supposedly around 15-20 ms, and the errors add up at each iteration, which makes it a bit impractical.

However it is possible to work around this issue by starting a `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`  at the same time as the `DispatcherTimer` and checking the `StopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` inside the Tick Event with a smaller time step, and that seems to give more precise results. It also works with a `System.Timers.Timer`.

Here's a short example based on a WPF program I made.

```
private void StartTimers(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dtimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dtimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dTimer_Tick);
    dtimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);  // the small time step

    stopWatch = new StopWatch();

    dTimer.Start();
    stopWatch.Start();
}

private void dTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
     currentTime = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        if (currentTime - oldTime > interval)
        {
            oldTime = currentTime;
            DoStuff();
        }
}
```

Using `StopWatch.Restart` in the Tick Event to do iterations will have the same error problem the `DispatchTimer` causes, because it's going to restart when the DispatchTimer event is fired.